# Unable to connect to iCloud after phone reset

Tags: iphone, icloud, setup

My daughter reset her iPhone 6S.  After doing that she realized she had forgotten her AppleID password.  She requested password recovery yesterday.  Today she went to an Apple store and was able to chose a new password for her AppleID.  She is able to log into iTunes etc. on a web browser.

**The problem** is when she is setting up the phone (after resetting with iTunes) she is unable to "Restore from iCloud" or "Set up as new iPhone".  When asked to input her AppleID and password she gets the error "Could not sign in -
There was an error connecting to iCloud" (after a long while).  We know her password is correct and when she intentionally inputs wrong password she gets a verification error message.  Wifi is connected with plenty of bandwidth.

I anyone has ideas for me to try I would very much appreciate them.